# Long lived facebook token not returning expire time anymore?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have been using Facebook signin in one of my application where I exchange the short-lived token with a long-lived token as mentioned on this [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension)

And as a response for this exchange, FB used to return me the following data `access_token=<tokenvalue>&expires=<expiry_time>`

However, my application started breaking today and after investigation I see that Facebook is not returning `expires` anymore. Can anyone shed some light and help me in understanding the reason for this?

**Update:**

I'm currently using the following code to get the long lived token

```
token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&" \
                "client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&fb_exchange_token={2}".format(
                    settings.FACEBOOK_APP_ID, settings.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET, access_token
                )
    response = urllib2.Request(token_url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(response)
    response = response.read()
```

And the current response I get is: 
`access_token=<access_token_value>`

Old response was:
`access_token=<token_value>&expires=<expiry_time>`

Comment: The data isn’t returned in that format any more, since API v2.3 it returns JSON instead. Make sure your app handles that correctly.

Comment: @CBroe I updated my question, please take a look. how do I specify the API version? The documentation doesn't say anything about specifying api version in my `token_url`?

Comment: I had to deauthorize and reauthorize app and it worked